# declaring an int variable

Tags: c++, declaration

```
for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
```

I declared a variable in my code as above an received a compile-time error: something like such a declaration is obsolete according to ISO standards.

Then I declared the variable **outside** the for loop like this

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < size; i++)
```

.......and it worked????

Can somebody tell me about this declaration because as far as i know in C++ we can declare the variable not just at the top as in c but anywhere below while we need it.

The compiler that I was using is gcc.

Comment: Are you *really* using C+++? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: i was compiling on solaris with g++( not gcc) soory about the mistake above

Comment: paste your commandline with which you are compiling

Answer (score 2):

You were probably compiling with gcc instead of g++ (or xl_C instead of xl_C++ etc.)

Otherwise, check that you are not passing an old standard (with -std=c89 or -ansi)

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration declares `i` only in the scope of the for loop. The second declares it in the scope immediately outside. Both are perfectly valid. You would use the second case when you want to use the value of `i` after the loop, this would in general be the case where you had a `break` clause in the loop and wanted to find out on which iteration you broke out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks guys I got it was just surprised about that error anyway I think I might have to look at the code again and bring out the source code here  so that evry body can have a look at it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I will guess that you are using `i` after the loop ends.

Once upon a time, the first bit of code was equivalent to the second, declaring `i` in the scope *outside* the loop, so code like this was possible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    // do something
}

if (i != size) {
    // do something else
}
```

In Standard C++, this is invalid; `i` is only available in the body of the loop, and you need to declare it outside the loop to access it there.